# Linux Kernel 4.7 (Arch ARM64) does not create "resource0" file in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/ for PCI BAR0

Tags: linux, arm, fpga, mmap, pci-bus

I am working on a project where I need to access a FPGA memory through PCI BAR0 from userspace.

What I used to do in older kernels is open the file named **resource0** which is located in **/sys/bus/pci/devices/my_device/** and then use the **mmap()** function which exposes the FPGA memory to the userspace.

Unfortunately, in kernel version 4.7 (architecture ARM64) it seems that for some reason resource0 file is not created.

When I use the **lspci** I can see that the system recognizes the PCI BARs of the FPGA.
In addition, when I search the **/sys/bus/pci/devices/my_device/** directory I can see that there is a file named **resource** which has among others the addresses of the PCI BARs written in it.

Is anyone familiar with a similar situation?
How can I make linux create the **resource0** file?

Comment: Probably your older kernels were 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your concern, you can try this out of Tree patch which was not accepted upstream.

https://patchwork.codeaurora.org/patch/2059/

http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2015-July/359435.html

It would help you to map PCI resource file in user space.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
It seems that this workaround is the solution to my problem but I am not aware of how to apply a patch!
I will give feedback when I manage to test it.

Comment: The comment on the patch suggested using vfio-pci. Perhaps you can use that module too instead of sysfs.